# if condition depends on first column and the result show at second column in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want to write a condition which depends on first column 
 if found at first  column word called long  then write red in second column
,if found at the first column also word short  then as result 
 write white  in second column 
else write green

[image]

that what I need s result in table down and I want to get also effect on colour on the map.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a plugin for auto updating the color field, then use an expression that evaluates your 'type' field values and returns the colors.

ie. this plugin http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/

and the expression on the 'color' field could be something like:

```
CASE 
   WHEN "type" = 'long' THEN 'red'
   WHEN "type" = 'short' THEN 'white'
   ELSE 'green'
END
```

I just tested this out on a test file i created, and it worked fine. If you don't need the auto update but only needs the colors a single time, then just use the field calculator in the attribute table. Check the 'update existing field' box then select the field with the colors (take a backup of the layer first).

For styling the map with the colors, go to the layer properties (right click the layer) then choose 'symbologi' then either choose 'graduated' or 'categorized' for the effect you want. However you do not need to have a color field for styling with the colors you want.
You can just use the categorized colors on the 'type' field, then click 'classify' and map the long, short, medium values directly to the colors you want to see on the map.